# Logging Instrument approach if if entering IMC past the FAF, but in VMC before and passing the FAF

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, logging, precision-approach

Can an Instrument rated pilot log an instrument approach if  entered IMC past the FAF to minimums but was VMC prior and just past the FAF? What is your source?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, IAPs are designed to bring aircraft down through IMC conditions to the airport environment to make a landing. If IMC conditions are encountered at any point between FAF and DA/MDA, the approach can be logged. [FAA InFO 15012](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/InFO15012.pdf) provides guidance on what requirements have to be met in order to log an IAP.

Example 1 on page 3 is the most similar to the question you are asking:

> Example 1: An instrument-rated pilot, conducting a flight under an IFR clearance, approaches the destination airport, aligned with runway 33 and 17 miles out. ATC issues a clearance that states, “. . . cleared ILS runway (RWY) 33R approach as published, maintain 3000, advise when established.” The pilot operates the aircraft solely by reference to instruments, complies with the clearance, and continues in IMC—while remaining established as published on each required IAP segment. The aircraft descends past the final approach fix (FAF) as the pilot contacts the control tower and the aircraft transitions from IMC to visual metrological conditions (VMC) before reaching the DA. At this point, the pilot receives an ATC clearance to land; the pilot visually confirms runway environment assured and lands. In this example, the IAP complies with § 61.51(g)(3) and § 61.57(c); therefore, the pilot may log this IAP.

Answer (score 1):

[FAA InFO 15012](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/InFO15012.pdf) says that the approach must be done under actual or simulated instrument conditions, or a combination thereof, with the aircraft being operated solely by reference to instruments, for every required approach segment. It allows for approaches to be counted if the approach is conducted in IMC and the pilot breaks out beyond the final approach fix, but it does *not* give a similar exception for any other part of the approach.

So it seems that the answer is no- you would need to be wearing a hood from the point you initiate the approach all the way to when you first enter IMC. Once you are in actual IMC you can take the hood off, and then once you break out you can land and log the approach.